# Launch image and preloader

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios

I'm developping an application/web site accessible from PC and IOS. When I go on application with a navigator from PC and IOS, I can see the preloader, but when I add the web site like application on ios, there is a launch image. But the launch image hides the preloader and i can see it when the launch image loaded all informations.
But I don't want launch image loads all informations, I want see the preloader load.
How can't remove launch image. Or how can i make sure i see the preloader I added.
Thank you for your attention.

PS Sorry for my english ><

Comment: Set a black image with a loading icon and read the webView class references to start loading the view after the app has loaded - just a suggestion http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank you, but i develop in html/javascript. I'm sorry, it's my fault. I didn't say. :/

Comment: Ok, so who is building your IOS app? If you do it yourself you need to learn how to do it. You can't just copy/paste everything and have an application. BTW if you submit the application with just a web view **it will be rejected**

Comment: I develop this web app myself. It's just for me and i just ask some help. I just want suggestions, not code... Nevermind. Thank you for your help.